# Can a loadrequest cause "WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process"?

Tags: interstitial

My app is just a quiz app and does not access the web or use any web view

The error message starts with:
WF: === Starting WebFilter logging for process XXXXXXXXXXX
2017-01-23 22:16:14.120062 XXXXXXXXXXX[533:58517] WF: _userSettingsForUser mobile:

```
{
    filterBlacklist =     (
    );
    filterWhitelist =     (
    );
    restrictWeb = 1;
    useContentFilter = 0;
    useContentFilterOverrides = 0;
    whitelistEnabled = 0;
}
```

Then the error message is listed for several times:WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO

the app then runs out of memory

The error messages appear seemingly after:
[self.interstitial loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];

Please help

Comment: I have the same thing. I'm thinking the load request is making a web API call to retrieve the ads, but I have no idea why I suddenly started getting these messages or what they really mean. If I discover an answer, I'll post it here...

Answer (score 0):

The Mobile Ads SDK team [believes this is nothing to worry about](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/tDEa6H9LlkY):

> This seems to be iOS10+ specific and should not affect ad serving in any way.